# Invoke Laravel Controller Method on Start

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Where should I call a controller method, **not** from a client request but within the Laravel app when the app is up and running. I saw `schedule,` but it seems right for repeated tasks but not for a direct call.

Answer (score 0):

You can call public Controller functions from almost anywhere in your Laravel app via the `app()->make()` method, followed by the function name:

```
$exampleController = app()->make(ExampleController::class);
return $exampleController->exampleFunction();
```

Note: Provide the correct Namespace in the `->make()` function:

```
$exampleController = app()->make(\App\Http\Controllers\ExampleController::class) ...
```

and if there are any parameters for `exampleFunction()`, be sure to pass them:

```
$exampleParam = 1;
return $exampleController->exampleFunction($exampleParam);
```

Comment: That's great but still I don't know an appropriate place to invoke the method

Comment: *"[...] call public Controller functions from **almost anywhere** in your Laravel app"* - This tells you how, you need to decide where. I'm not sure what you want this controller function to do, so I can't really tell you...

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to move that method to main Controller class located at `app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php` and call it from any child controller using `$this`.

Make sure that method is protected or public. Private methods are not accessible in Child controllers.